# Dockerfile & installation -> Package 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' has no installation candidate

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to install openjdk-8-jre vie DockerFile, as I build the docker images for my composer. But I'm hitting this error message.

Error message:

```
Package openjdk-8-jre-headless is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' has no installation candidate
```

Here is the part from Dockerfile:

```
# Install openjdk and java cacerts
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java
```

If I install java directly from the console, by using exact same command without RUN, no problem with the package. But as I try installing it from the Dockerfile, I hit the error. I have understood that Docker uses same repos as the machine where docker is running? Ubuntu is version 16.04.

Or how I check available installation packages on Dockerfile? java - v gives an error..

Comment: "Works fine" *on the exact same machine*? Note that if this is a Docker instance, it's running a different distro than your outer host (that's the whole point!), so package names &c. can be different. We'd know which specific version of Ubuntu your successful test was on, and which specific version of Ubuntu the failure was on, to be able to speak conclusively.

Comment: (part of why I strongly suspect you're running Docker is the misprinting of commands -- to get your error, the command would need to really be run as `/bin/sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java'` with the quotes, but even though it correctly behaves as if the quotes were there when it's actually running, Docker leaves them out when printing error messages).

Comment: ...can you share a Dockerfile that generates the error? (It can be cut down to a [mre], with all commands that *aren't* necessary to generating the error in question removed).

Comment: What are you building `FROM`? i.e. `debian:buster`(`-slim`) (and images based on i.e. [`python:3.7-slim`](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/c3233a936f58bee7c6899d3e381f23ed12cfc7a8/3.7/buster/slim/Dockerfile)) doesn't have `openjdk-8-jre-headless` in the `apt` repos (hit that wall, upgraded to `openjdk-11`) ref. the [online package search](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-8-jre-headless). No, `docker` uses the repo's of the operating system that you're building `FROM`.

Comment: How can I check the installation packages on Dockerfile? java -version gives error about java..

Comment: will this help: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/c597462ebad14ab0181ec6051ac4deaca396cd77/Dockerfile#L8

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `FROM python:3.8 as base` and as mentioned by @masseyb in the comment under your question it does not have openjdk-8jre-headless package.

This may help you.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine as base
RUN apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache bash \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies unzip \
&& apk add --no-cache curl \
&& apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
rm -r /root/.cache

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org flask
```

This example Dockerfile can get you Java python and flask